# Azure AD graph API to Search multiple users based on UserPrincipalName and Mail

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way in Graph API where advance query able to search group of users based on Email id and User Principal Name.
We are using filter parameter with "in" clause to search users
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=userPrincipalName in ('abc@xyz.com','pqr@xyz.com','guest#external@xyz.com)

Above URL works charm. But we see Mail instead of userPrincipalName, we are decided to query based on Mail or UserPrincipalName property. Is there any support for graph api to search against Mail and UPN property in single call. I tried with signInNames or otherMails or issuerAssignedId but they are not supported. Any better way for querying both UPN and Mail

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 4):

•   You can use the ‘OR’ in advanced query filter parameter to search for multiple users’ based on ‘UPN’ and ‘mail’ in a single query call as below: -

‘ https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=mail in ('lobo@def.com') or userPrincipalName in ('abc@xyz.com') ‘

The above query will give the details of the users based on UPN as well as mail attribute and fetch the same data from Azure AD related to the users. It will fetch all the general information that is available in Azure AD.

Please find the below link for more details on using the OR operator: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter

Comment: we are searching for user count of 100. in those cases, we hit url limit. I'm planning to try with $batch api of graph

Comment: When you run the query in MS Graph and are expecting more results than what are displayed in the screen, the graph explorer provides a link as a query to go to the next set of displayed output list. It is shown as '@odata.nextLink' in the graph explorer output. Just copy the link and paste it in the query box of the graph explorer and run the query to get next set of results.

Comment: thanks kartik, I'm saying about "in" query parameter where number of users to query are more than 100

Comment: No issues with it, even if the number of users is more than 100, then also, the above mentioned resolution will help in displaying the users accordingly, though not all on the same page, in the subsequent pages.